# io.streamwriter Can't write to text file after async task

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, streamwriter

I'm running the following code in an asynchronus sub and it's failing on "Test 2" write to a text file. I've tried writing asynchronously and synchronously and it fails when trying to write after the line `BoxFldr = Await BoxFldrMgr.GetInformationAsync(id)`. This code is in a recursive sub and the streamwriter open/close is done in the sub calling this. Any ideas?

```
BoxFldrMgr = BoxClient.FoldersManager
BoxFileMgr = BoxClient.FilesManager
Debug.Print("Test write 1")
Await objWriter.WriteLineAsync("Test 1")
Debug.Print("getting folder details")
BoxFldr = Await BoxFldrMgr.GetInformationAsync(id)
Debug.Print("Test write 2")
Await objWriter.WriteLineAsync("Test 2")
```

It's failing with this error:
    A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fail" ? That word is very broad.

Comment: Give like @the_lotus said a detailed error explanation. But I think the problem is after writing the first string you try to access again the file, which is actually "open" so I think that is maybe an ´UnauthorizedAccessException´?

Comment: @R.Gomez : He never seems to close/reopen the `StreamWriter`, in which case he already has access to the file handle. If he hasn't left anything out between the lines he shows us _and_ the first write succeeds, then that code won't throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: Sorry, here's the error I'm getting:

Comment: I updated the post with my error and to clarify